# stanford corenlp not working

Tags: python, parsing, stanford-nlp, linguistics

I'm using Windows 8, and running python in eclipse with pyDev.

I installed Stanford coreNLP (python version) from the site:
https://github.com/relwell/stanford-corenlp-python

When I try to import corenlp, I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ghantauke\workspace\PythonTest2\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import corenlp
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\corenlp\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from corenlp import StanfordCoreNLP, ParserError, TimeoutError, ProcessError
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\corenlp\corenlp.py", line 28, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pexpect.py", line 85, in <module>
    support it. Pexpect is intended for UNIX-like operating systems.""")
ImportError: No module named resource

A critical module was not found. Probably this operating system does not
support it. Pexpect is intended for UNIX-like operating systems.
```

Does that mean the python fork of it doesn't work in windows? Is there any way I can make it work in windows?

If not then could you suggest other alternatives that I could use in windows. I just need the parser.

Comment: I have a similar issue with Windows Server 2012, I can't get Pexpect so the python wrapper is unusable as-is. Diving...

Comment: OK, seems to be working now... @ghantauke if you still need this, you could try the answer below.

Comment: Install [cygwin](http://cygwin.org/), and be sure to select the python that they provide. Then run it in cygwin, and I expect it should work.

Comment: I'll check my cygwin install again...

Comment: You could also use a VM machine.  Bit more overhead than cygwin though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a record of my attempts to get `corenlp-python`, the python wrapper for [CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/downloads/corenlp.shtml) running on Windows Server 2012, as-is.

> **Disclaimer:** should you only need to run an executable, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320816) first. Consider `subprocess`.

#### Starting out

Since `corenlp-python` uses `pexpect` fairly heavily, and that library works on UNIX only, my first thought was to find a Windows port.

[wexpect.py](http://mediarealm.com.au/articles/2014/01/python-pexpect-windows-wexpect/) was fairly easy to find and claims to be a drop-in replacement for Pexpect (emphasis mine):

> In order to use WExpect, you must install CygWin, and then install the WExpect script into your system **(dropping the py file into your working directory is usually good enough)**.
>   I’ve found the functionality is pretty much the same, so you should be able to use the PExpect manual and examples and apply them to this Microsoft Windows variant.

So I did just that, downloading and installing CygWin, then copying `wexpect.py` into `C:\Python27\lib\` where all the other libraries were. I tried to `import wexpect` from a Python shell and got an error similar to when I first tried Pexpect on Windows:

```
ImportError: No module named pywintypes
This module requires the win32 python packages.

A critical module was not found. Probably this operating system does not
support it. Pexpect is intended for UNIX-like systems.
```

#### Et tu, wexpect?

No matter, this is standard frustration for finding equivalents. Press on.

I opened `wexpect.py` and saw that it would only try `pywintypes` on a Windows system. Logical, so I tried:

```
$ pip install -U pywintypes
```

...which failed, and led me to Google for the name of the python Win32 packages ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907889/importerror-no-module-named-pywintypes) helped):

```
$ pip install -U pywin32
```

...which prompts for `--allow-external` and then `--allow-unverified`, both of which expect the package name, ergo:

```
$ pip install --allow-external pywin32 --allow-unverified pywin32 pywin32
```

Which, of course, does not work. No such package is found.

#### sf.net

So I head off to search for [pywin32 on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pywin32&submit=search) and realise that [only a readme is left](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32/214) and I have to jump through four MORE hoops to get to [something more substantial](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/), then two more to find [this list](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/).

I downloaded [Build 219 for Python 2.7 32-bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe/download). At least now `import wexpect` doesn't puke.

#### What did you expect?

So I run the `corenlp-python` command again, and this time it's missing `unidecode`. This was easier to fix, and finally I got to a usable state - an error, no less, but familiar - where the path to the JARs was not correct.

#### OK.

When you run `corenlp.py`, since `pexpect` is invoked, remember to `import wexpect as pexpect` near the top and comment out the real `import pexpect` line, or you will get a `NameError`:

```
#import pexpect
import wexpect as pexpect
```

Even with Java installed, this does not seem to work, regardless of path.

```
$ python lib\corenlp\corenlp.py
```

It returns an `ExceptionPexpect`.

Comment: I've since stopped working as much on this, as I was able to coerce the Windows machine to connect to the NLP server running on a Linux VM.