# corenlp.py is throwing not create the Java Virtual Machine Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to implement the dependency parser using stanford-corenlp-python wrapper.

Since I am using Windows Platform which gives error for pexpect package while execution, I spend some time to install wexpect for Windows and follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704590/stanford-corenlp-not-working) and completed the setup. Now when I am trying to execute corenlp.py again, I am getting following error and program is getting terminated.
Please help me with this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "corenlp.py", line 258, in <module>
    nlp = StanfordCoreNLP()
  File "corenlp.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.corenlp.expect("done.", timeout=20) # Load pos tagger model (~5sec)
  File "/cygdrive/f/Masters-Spring2015/Natural Language Processing/Project/stanford-corenlp-python/wexpect.py", line 1356, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list, timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/cygdrive/f/Masters-Spring2015/Natural Language Processing/Project/stanford-corenlp-python/wexpect.py", line 1370, in expect_list
    return self.expect_loop(searcher_re(pattern_list), timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/cygdrive/f/Masters-Spring2015/Natural Language Processing/Project/stanford-corenlp-python/wexpect.py", line 1441, in expect_loop
    raise EOF (str(e) + '\n' + str(self))
wexpect.EOF: End Of File (EOF) in read_nonblocking(). Empty string style platform.
<wexpect.spawn_unix object at 0x7fdad40c>
version: 2.3 ($Revision: 399 $)
command: /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/java
args: ['/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/java', '-Xmx1800m', '-cp', './stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27/stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar:./stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27/stanford-corenlp-3.4.1-models.jar:./stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27/joda-time.jar:./stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27/xom.jar:./stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27/jollyday.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP', '-props', 'default.properties']
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile("done.")
buffer (last 100 chars):
before (last 100 chars):  not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
after: <class 'wexpect.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: True
pid: 7104
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'wexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `stanford-corenlp-python` wrapper starts a server which spawns an instance of the command line interface for CoreNLP, receives sentences on HTTP, pipes sentences to the spawned CLI instance via `stdin`, takes the `stdout` result, parses it, and sends back sentences via HTTP, then parses it again in the process which sent the request in the first place.

The error you're seeing--that `wexpect` is getting an unexpected EOF--looks like the spawned instance of the CoreNLP CLI is crashing. This is probably because you're running this in Cygwin. Cygwin looks like unix, but when it needs to do really unix-y things, like run other programs, things that require genuine interaction with the operating system, it starts to turn into garbage.

I'm guessing you went Cygwin because you can't use pexpect on the Windows command line, and the `stanford-corenlp-python` wrapper uses it. From [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#requirements)'s docs, though:

> Pexpect only works on POSIX systems, where the pty module is present in the standard library. It may be possible to run it on Windows using Cygwin.

It think we're seeing an instance here where pexpect fails on Cygwin.

My recommendation: don't use the `stanford-corenlp-python` wrapper; it is slow and buggy. Even after you get this working, something else will be wrong, and even after you get it running, it will drag out the processing tremendously.

Instead, run CoreNLP directly from the command line. If you have a batch job to do, use a filelist. The output is XML; you can parse that / grep it, and be on your way. From the [CoreNLP home page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml):

> If you want to process a list of files use the following command line:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-VV.jar:stanford-corenlp-VV-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar:ejml-VV.jar -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP [ -props <YOUR CONFIGURATION FILE> ] -filelist <A FILE CONTAINING YOUR LIST OF FILES>
```

Let me tell you about my own experience using the wrapper. The last time I used the `stanford-corenlp-python` wrapper, it took 17800 documents two weeks to process. That was after a good week or two of tweaking the code to handle the large quantity of news articles I was about to pass it.

Later, I got a new computer and ran CoreNLP through the command line directly, no wrapper except some python and shell scripting to help create a target file list for the batch jobs. It took 24000 documents 15 hours process. The new computer helped, but I anticipated maybe a 4x performance gain from the new hardware. The other 26x was from dropping the wrapper.

Considering how the `stanford-corenlp-python` wrapper is written, it's not surprising that it's slow and buggy. Between all the crazy layers of processing it does, I'm amazed they got it working at all. You're better off, though, just running on the command line, especially since you won't have to run it in Cygwin.